# Are individual yml files needed for each component param option?

Tags: jss, datasource, components

As an example, I'll use a generic content `Block` component. This component, among other params, would have a `columnSpan` param. As far as I can tell, the only way to predefine options for that param is to create individual content entries like so:

[image]

...and use that directory as the `source` of the params like so:

```
{
  ...
  source: 'dataSource=sitecore/content/BlockColumnSpanOptions'
  ...
}
```

So, multiply that by X number of components and X number of params, this content directory is quickly going to become nightmarish.

Is there a better/other way to provide param options in a more flattened/simplified manner?

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manifest API is a JavaScript API; we just provide a default input via YAML. You can modify the handling in `/sitecore/definitions/*.sitecore.js` to source content from whatever you like, including multiple items in one JS file.

[Example here](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/d0549adff90b09690be53940094afa6c45509d3d/samples/react/sitecore/definitions/content.sitecore.js#L33), note that the manifest contains TypeScript typings to make constructing objects easier.